# A better Ruby implementation of round decimal to nearest 0.5

Tags: ruby, math, decimal, rounding

This seems horrible inefficient. Can someone give me a better Ruby way.

```
def round_value
  x = (self.value*10).round/10.0 # rounds to two decimal places
  r = x.modulo(x.floor) # finds remainder
  f = x.floor

  self.value = case
  when r.between?(0, 0.25)
    f
  when r.between?(0.26, 0.75)
    f+0.5
  when r.between?(0.76, 0.99)
    f+1.0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
class Float
  def round_point5
    (self * 2).round / 2.0
  end
end
```

A classic problem: this means you're doing integer rounding with a different radix. You can replace '2' with any other number.

Comment: As this solution adds the method to the Ruby-Class itself, you can use it like this: `(2.45).round_point5` or `x.round_point5`

Comment: class Decimal - is that a Rails thing? And what is 'value'?

Comment: woah, thanks @steenslag - fixed the value thing which was blatently wrong. I also changed Decimal to Float, because while there is a Decimal class (and the OP mentions decimal in the title), that's probably not what they meant now that you mention it...

Comment: Never monkey patch standard Ruby objects.  Implement this in a Helper or some sort of Utility PORO.  The main reason being testability.  Do you really want a `stdlib/float_spec.rb` in your `/specs` directory?  The second being what if you'd like to apply this to logic to other Numeric/Decimal types?  BigDecimal, etc.  You'd have to monkey patch those Objects too - and write and maintain more tests!

Comment: @danielricecodes Never say never.

Answer (score 13):

Multiply the number by two.

round to whole number.

Divide by two.

```
(x * 2.0).round / 2.0
```

In a generalized form, you multiply by the number of notches you want per whole number (say round to .2 is five notches per whole value). Then round; then divide by the same value.

```
(x * notches).round / notches
```

Comment: if you divide by 2 it will truncate due to integer division. I also initially had this problem in my solution :) Divide by 2.0 instead.

Comment: @Peter Thanks. @JoshD Thanks for the added explanation. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a `modulo` operator too.

```
(x + (0.05 - (x % 0.05))).round(2)
```

If x = 1234.56, this will return 1234.6

I stumbled upon this answer because I am writing a Ruby-based calculator and it used Ruby's Money library to do all the financial calculations.  Ruby Money objects do not have the same rounding functions that an Integer or Float does, but they can return the remainder (e.g. modulo, `%`).

Hence, using Ruby Money you can round a Money object to the nearest $25 with the following:

```
x + (Money.new(2500) - (x % Money.new(2500)))
```

Here, if x = $1234.45 (<#Money fractional:123445 currency:USD>), then it will return $1250.00 (#

NOTE: There's no need to round with Ruby Money objects since that library takes care of it for you!